# Wordpress rewrites HTML pasted by curl

Tags: php, html, wordpress, curl

I am working on website that is using Wordpress, my problem is that when i put curl php code inside my post, the html pasted by that curl gets reformated by Wordpress and all css on the original page is messed up.

This is my php in post:

```
$ch = curl_init('mypage');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
```

And this exaple of how it reformates the HTML:

```
<div class='deal'>
    <a href='link'>
        <img src='image' width='600px' height='auto'>
        <p><b>Text</b></p>
        <span class='discount'>-57%</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

gets changed to:

```
<div class="deal">
    <a href="link">
        <img src="image" width="600px" height="auto">
        <p><b>Text</b></p>
    </a>
    <a href="link">
        <span class="discount">-57%</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there any way to prevent this from happaning? Thanks ~BeefEX

Comment: It's replacing single with double quotes and adding some spaces or tabs. Am I missing something? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: it adds whole new <a> tag